# Why does my curl command not work with my php code

Tags: php, forms, ubuntu, curl, post

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="POST" action="a.php">
    <input type=text name="email">
    <input type=submit name=press value=" OK ">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code is my php page.
when i use command "curl -d "abc=111" http://localhost/test.php"
this is no response, just print the code again...is there any problem with it?

Comment: You need to pass the POST to the ACTION of the form, not the HTML page. so you should do `curl -d "abc=111" http://localhost/a.php` Also the name of your field is email, so I assume you want to do something like `curl -d "email=test@test.com" http://localhost/a.php`

Comment: Thanks for your information, I've modified the filed name and try with curl -d "email=111@test.com" http://localhost/a.php  However,it still doesn't work. What problem it may be?

Comment: Please update your original question to include the `a.php` file code so we can try and understand

Comment: Andrea Olivato, Thanks for your help. It works! I make a stupid mistake that does not install PHP module... Really appreciate.